Creating and running a VxWorks demo project with Simics simulation as target
I've been tasked with creating a VxWorks dummy project and run it on Simics simulation (as a feasibility study and also come up with user guide after that). But here are the constraints:

I donot have any simics licenses (I'm assuming we can still use Simics base package and some built in license free target)
VxWorks project can be GUI or Shell, and can be any target

Can you give pointers on how to go about this?
I am able to run simics built-in simulation (QSP x86) separately; but not sure how to connect my dummy VxWorks project to it. Or is there a way to just kick off simics from within VxWorks Workbench and run my helloWorld project on it?

Your best bet would likely be to contact Wind River for assistance, though you should be able to create a VSB and VIP based on the itl_generic BSP configured for the Nehalem CPU then simply substitute your newly built vxWorks image for the QSP-X86's $vxworks_image parameter.

Thanks. WindRiver wasn't of much help in mycase as I donot have license. Because of that I'm trying to run Intel Simics now (So Intel Simics + VxWorks QSP x86 is what I am trying out now)

That makes sense, but the key is still to get an image created from VxWorks that can boot on a real machine, and use it in the equivalent place on the QSP. Preferably, a bootable disk image that boots from UEFI.

Appreciate your resopnse @jakobengblom2, I tried loading my self-created VxWorks image on to the Simics X86 UEFI, but I was getting different types of memory related problems reported by Simics. Then it dawned on me that the image I loaded maynot be UEFI compliant. Having a go at creating the right image to work with Simics X86 UEFI now.

The QSP-X86 featured in the public release of Simics is a generic PC model that should run a generic X86 BPS from VxWorks.  You might want to use a more modern processor model in case a modern VxWorks wants some specific MSRs.
Build a bootable disk model out of VxWorks, and use that instead of the Linux image. I am pretty sure the tools for VxWorks can do that.

Thanks @jakobengblom2, Intel Simics + VxWorks QSP x86 is what I am trying out now as recommended by my team because of the license issues with Windriver Simics. I'm hoping this is feasible.
